# Meteor: how to check if an user is logged in from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension for my Meteor app. Is it possible for the chrome extension to check if a user has logged in the Meteor app?

I was thinking to send `Meteor.user()` data from Meteor app to chrome extension whenever a user tries to login and logout. But I am not sure if that's the right way to do it.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated

If your Meteor app stores login info in a cookie, you could detect if a user has logged in by checking the cookies for your Meteor app url.

Take a look at [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) and [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), you could either use `chrome.cookies` in background page or just use `document.cookie` in content scripts.

### <del>Previous</del>

<del>If you mean there are two ways to login your Meteor app, one is from normal web page and the other is chrome extension. Then I think you could check the login source by the analyse the http request.</del>

<del>You could check `origin` of the http request, if the request is sent from extension background, the `origin` would look like `chrome-extension://xxxxx`. Or you could send extra info as a flag when sending login info.</del>

Comment: I apologize for my English. I meant to ask if it is possible for the chrome extension to check if a user has logged in the Meteor app.

Comment: @Yichen, is your login info stored in cookies? How about checking the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access to your app's objects from a Chrome extension but you will have access to the DOM. What I suggest you do is include a DOM element (even a hidden one) that indicates whether or not a user is logged in and have your extension look for that.

Comment: Right now I am using window.postMessage in the Meteor app to communicate with the extension `window.postMessage({foo: foo, bar: bar}, targetUrl);`. I can send variables that way, is it not secure? Thanks!

Comment: That is fine, you're only sending a status. The approach I was suggesting was basically passive from the view of the app. Your approach involves a tiny bit more work but will be fine.